# Get object on onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I make a new activity that create a Bluetooth device object. When I need return this using onActivityResult() method, I have a problem.

**Child activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("BluetoothDevice", DeviceArrayList.get(arg2));
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

DeviceArrayList.get(arg2) is the device Object.

**Parent activity**

```
 BluetoothDevice btDevice;
...

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                    btDevice = data.getExtras("BluetoothDevice");

                }
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Resultado cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }//onActivityResult
```

Who I can get the object in btDevice?

Comment: Jose M : Is your BluetoothDevice is Serilizable or Parceable buddy ??? You can pass only Serializable or Parceable object in intent :)

Comment: mm.. I don't know :( I this case, i can serialize it?

Comment: If you are using android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice it extends Parcelable,so you can use intent.putParcelable("key",object)

Comment: I use android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice; :) How to parceable it?

Comment: @Jose M : tthan just follow darwin's instruction :) Thats all you need :)

Comment: So you can use intent.putParcelable(key, object); and use BluetoothDevice device = data.getParcelable(key) for retrieving the value

Comment: @darwin- Cannot resolve method  intent.putParcelable:(

Comment: You can use Bundle for adding parceble object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your bluetooth device class serializabale or parceable. And then you can pass it to the second activity using intent:

```
intent.putExtra("bluetooth", myBluetoothDeviceObject);
```

And you can get the same in your second activity using:

```
intent.getParcelableExtra("bluetooth")
```

I prefer parceable over serializable. 
Please look at the android docs for more info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Answer (score 1):

make BluetoothDevice  class serializable and in onActivityResult cast it like that

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                btDevice =(BluetoothDevice)data.getSerializableExtra("BluetoothDevice");

            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Resultado cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }//onActivityResult
```